# vb.net LINQ LEFT JOIN

Tags: vb.net, linq

I want query LINQ to `LEFT JOIN TWO TABLES` get results like SQL exactly 
(show results like the picture even the row empty yellow line)

My code:

```
Dim qJoint = From tSum In lstSUM Group Join tbnk In lstBank On tbnk.ID_BANK Equals tSum.ID_BANK _
   Into tResult = Group From tbnk In tResult.DefaultIfEmpty Select tbnk.ID_BANK, tbnk.ABRIGER, tbnk.NomBank_AR, tSum.Montant_Facture
```

[image]

Comment: Show your code first, without it we cant help you.  We are not a code writing service.  Your question will just get down voted.

Comment: Dim qJoint = From tSum In lstSUM Group Join tbnk In lstBank On tbnk.ID_BANK Equals tSum.ID_BANK _
                   Into tResult = Group From tbnk In tResult.DefaultIfEmpty Select tbnk.ID_BANK, tbnk.ABRIGER, tbnk.NomBank_AR, tSum.Montant_Facture

Answer (score 0):

Little Problem Try Code:

```
Dim result=  from v in VW_sum_bybank 
            join b in tbl_bank on v.id_bank equals b.id_bank into jj from kk in  jj.DefaultIfEmpty()  
          select 
                  V_id_bank=v.id_banl,    
                  Code_bank=v.Code_bank,
                   NOMBANK=v.NOMBANK,
                  ABRG=v.ABRG,    
                  b_id_bank=kk.ID_bank,
                  sommeFAC=kk.sommeFAC
```